# geom_dot with different dot sizes for different groups and bring one to the front

Tags: r, ggplot2

From the following example I'm trying to have different formats for dots representing different "source" (s1 and s2). I would also like to bring one "source" to the front so that when the 2 sources overlap one of the two doesn't disappear if covered by dots from the other source.

In the example I created it looks like s2 is brought to the front and it is not hiding, but in my real data I have the opposite color and order assignment, so that I have dots that cannot be seen. Since I don't know how to control this I cannot fully replicate my problem.

```
rm(list=ls()) 
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

data<-rbind(
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,20,5),zone="zone1",source="s1"),
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(1,20,5),zone="zone1",source="s2"),
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,16,1),zone="zone2",source="s1"),
  data.frame(poll=rnorm(1,16,1),zone="zone2",source="s2"))

  p<-ggplot(data, aes(x=zone, y=poll,fill=source)) + 
    geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', binwidth=0.8, 
                 method="histodot",stackratio=0.8, dotsize=0.5)

  p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a general solution that will do exactly what you want. In your example data, one of the sources is consistently more prevalent, so could safely go behind, but this won't always be the case for all combinations of sources and all poll values for those sources.

*BTW, I modified a line of your sample to make this clearer:*
`data.frame(poll=rnorm(20,20,5),zone="zone1",source="s2"),`

I would suggest an alternate strategy that uses `dodge` or `stackgroups` to sidestep the front/back challenge altogether.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=zone, y=poll,fill=source)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', binwidth=0.8, 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.3),
               method="histodot",stackratio=0.8, dotsize=0.5)
```

[image]

The `stackgroups` feature doesn't look like it's fully baked, but maybe this can look better with tweaking:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=zone, y=poll,fill=source)) + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y',  binwidth=0.8,
               method="histodot", stackratio=0.8, dotsize=0.5,
               stackgroups = TRUE, stackdir = "center")
```

[image]